# WSL Ubuntu - How to change background-color of directory listing text in CMD/Powershell?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, powershell, colors, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I use WSL Ubuntu with either CMD/Powershell and the directory listing text-background always appear awful - In dark backgrounds, the text-background will be dark blue and the color blue (looks awful) and in bright background, the text-background will be very light blue with something like gray (or something of that sort); My point is that it seems someone worked a bit hard that it won't be very readable almost anytime.

Marking the text make it seem white on white-yellowish background which is also awful.

WSL is so great and CMD/Powershell as well; but this can sabotage some of the fun.

Is there a way to disable the background color for this text or at least **set this text to a single color that never changes**?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but see if `tput` is installed or if you can install it. If it's available, then see http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/01/tput-command-examples/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that replacing the standard Windows console with [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/) makes for a nicer appearance. There are numerous built-in color schemes, or you can make your own. I use it to run WSL, cmd, PowerShell, Cygwin, and more.